# Why do i get a [Text Object] instead of the expected TR object with previousSibling in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So if I have HTML code like this:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>This is a test</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <TABLE>
      <TR>
        <TD>First Cell</TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>Second Cell</TD>
        <TD><A href="#" onclick="alert(this.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling.childNodes[0].innerHTML); return false;">Click Here</A></TD>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

This works for Internet explorer, but not for Firefox and probably more browsers out there. Apparently Firefox interprets the whitespace between the TR's(indentation) as the previousSibling of the parent TR of 'this' in my code above. So instead of getting the desired TR object it gives me a [Text Object].

So my question now is, why doesn't Firefox ignore the whitespace between TR's like Internet Explorer does. I know I can use previousElementSibling to circumvent this, but i want to know why Firefox does this and if there is a logical explanation or a use for it. I've tried looking it up on the internet but to no avail. So if someone could tell me or give me a link where I can find this information, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct. It is actually IE that is principally wrong. [Here is Mozilla's take on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Whitespace_in_the_DOM)

You can

a) use parentNode.getElementsByTagName
b) flatten the dom by looping loop until nodeType is what you were looking for: 
Here is a simpler script than what Mozilla gave in the link above: http://blog.tegneblokken.net/2009/08/counting-childnodes-with-javascript-the-whitespace-incident/
c) use jQuery

Comment: 1) can you elaborate on "flatten the dom", i don't quite get what you mean. 2) I'm not going to use jQuery as its library is huge, and just using it for this tiny bit of code is useless. 3) I'm not interested in how to solve this issue, because i already have. The question is why Firefox interprets the whitespace as [Text Object]

Comment: I think i'm going to use a) since it is a short piece of code, that will work for all browsers. Thnx!

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace between elements is significant in HTML and in many situations affects rendering, even in IE, so IE is the weirdo here.

You could write simple functions to mask this difference:

```
function previousSibling(node) {
    while ( (node = node.previousSibling) && node.nodeType == 3 && /^\s*$/.test(node.data));
    return node;
}

function nextSibling(node) {
    while ( (node = node.nextSibling) && node.nodeType == 3 && /^\s*$/.test(node.data));
    return node;
}
```

Comment: +1 for you. Thnx for the reply, i might want to consider this in the future!